# Windows 10 full download of USB boot

Tags: boot, usb, windows-10

I'm having daily BSOD on my windows 10 update, and want to do a repair install using a USB boot as indicated here:

http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html

However, I currently am in Africa and only have 1 GB of internet every day through my mobile hotspot. Is there any way to fully download the USB boot media through a browser? With firefox I could download a small part every day.

Comment: Use a downloader software where you can pause a download and retrieve it the next day (ex.: http://jdownloader.org/)

Comment: If you want help with the BSOD you will have to provide more information.  BluescreenViewer will help proovide us the relevant information.  You need to submit the .dmp file so we can look at it yourself, or follow the existing question, that describes the process yourself.  In either case what you have provided isn't enough to help you.  You can simply use the built in Reset feature, you don't need the installation disk,to do what you want.  If you don't figure out the reason for the BSOD it will just happen again.

Comment: The ISO could be fully downloaded but whatever method MS uses isn't too happy about interrupted downloads. I'm tempted to suggest getting a friend with better internet to give you a hand.

Comment: You can download the .ISO through a browser by using [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench) method.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the methods MS has available officially seem friendly for this. Best option might be to find someone with unlimited internet to do it for you, and maybe image and split up the image.

Comment: Using the reset feature would mean I loose all my installed programs, which means I would have to download a lot again. The techbench might be a good option, I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: I didn't find anything that could work... The suggestion of Ramhound didn't work because the links are only live for 24h. So in the end I spent a lot of money on internet packs :)

Answer (score -1):

Use a download manager or a p2p torrent, both will allow you to pause and resume. Test if you browser allows you to pause downloads already. Start downloading, pause, and then resume a bit later on, if it resumes without losing whats already been downloaded you can do it that way.